# django redirect after POST not working

Tags: django, mongodb, django-views

I have apparently forgotten something really basic about django.  Here's my views.py:

```
def sourcedoc_create(request):

if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = SourcedocForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['doc'])
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/') # Redirect after POST
else:
    form = SourcedocForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response(
        'sourcedoc_create.html',
        {'form': form},
        RequestContext(request)
```

Here's the relevant part of urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', index),
url(r'^index/', index),
url(r'^sourcedoc/create/', sourcedoc_create),
```

When I run the app, I create the record in the database, and the uploaded file appears successfully in the relevant directory (thus I infer that the form.save worked ok), but then I get:

```
KeyError at /sourcedoc/create/

0

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://www.rosshartshorn.net/worldmaker/sourcedoc/create/
Django Version:     1.4.3
```

It appears that my HttpResponseRedirect is, for whatever reason, not working, and it's trying to re-POST and throwing a KeyError off a blank form?  Or something.  In any event, it's not redirecting.  When I manually go to /index/, all is well, and the new record is there.

Any ideas what is wrong with my redirect?

In case the forms are relevant:

```
  <body>
{% if form.errors %}
    <p style="color: red;">
        Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
    </p>
{% endif %}
<h1>New Post</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" method="post">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Also, I'm using mongoforms, which is supposed to work like ModelForms:

```
from mongodbforms import DocumentForm

class SourcedocForm(DocumentForm):
class Meta:
    document = Sourcedoc
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been at least somewhat related to this post: [Django MongodbForms KeyError _meta['cascade']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621235/django-mongodbforms-keyerror-metacascade).

So, I just upgraded to Django 1.5 and the newest mongodbforms.  This eliminated that error, although I was then getting a problem similar to this:
[MongoKit "ImportError: No module named objectid " error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401499/mongokit-importerror-no-module-named-objectid-error)

I just implemented keppla's answer from that second post, and it now seems to work!